# Add new attribute dynamically to the existing JSON array in Node

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, attributes

I need to add an attribute which doesn't exist in the current JSON. The json object looks like below.

```
var jsonObj = {
        "result" : "OK",
        "data" : []
    };
```

And I want to add temperature inside 'data'. I could do it like below.

```
jsonObj.data.push( {temperature : {}} );
```

And then, I want to add 'home', 'work' inside 'temperature'. The result would be like below.

```
{
    "result" : "OK",
    "data" : [
        { "temperature" : {
            "home" : 24,
            "work" : 20 } }
    ]
};
```

How could I do this? I succeeded to insert 'temperature' inside 'data', but couldn't add 'home' & 'work' inside temperature. There could be more inside the 'temperature' so it needs to be enclosed with {}.

Comment: It's confusing, but the term "JSON object" is a misnomer. In JavaScript, an object literal creates a plain old JavaScript object. The syntax is a *superset* of JSON syntax.

Comment: @Pointy  Thanks Pointy. Can I ask what makes this object a superset of JSON? (I thought this is a completely JSON object.)

Comment: Well because you're working in JavaScript, there is only one kind of object, and that's a JavaScript object :)  The JavaScript syntax for creating objects ("object literal" expressions) has existed for longer than the idea of JSON. In other languages, you'd normally construct JSON as a string. In JavaScript the syntax that *looks like* JSON syntax is just plain JavaScript syntax in reality, and you can do more with it than you can with JSON - like, have functions as property values, for example.

Comment: @Pointy I see. I'm actually using Node.js but I guess it's JavaScript also, right? Then I think I need to go and find out the definition of the JSON exactly. Thanks for the comment. If you have any more comments, please leave some. I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

How about this?

```
var temperature = { temperature: { home: 24, work: 20 }};

jsonObj.data.push(temperature);
```

I can't tell if doing it in two steps is important by how your question is structured, but you *could* add the home and work properties later by indexing into the array, like this:

```
jsonObj.data.push({ temperature: { }});

jsonObj.data[0].temperature.home = 24;
jsonObj.data[0].temperature.work = 20;
```

But, that's not a great idea since it depends on the array index to find the temperature object. If that's a requirement, it would be better to do something like loop through the `data` array to find the object you're interested in conclusively.

Edit:

An example of looping through to locate the temperature object would go something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < jsonObj.data.length; i++) { 
  if (jsonObj.data[i].temperature) { 
    break;
  }
}

jsonObj.data[i].temperature.home = 24;
jsonObj.data[i].temperature.work = 20;
```

Edit:

If which particular property you'll be interested in is unknown at development time, you can use bracket syntax to vary that:

```
for (var i = 0; i < jsonObj.data.length; i++) { 
  if (jsonObj.data[i]['temperature']) { 
    break;
  }
}

jsonObj.data[i]['temperature'].home = 24;
jsonObj.data[i]['temperature'].work = 20;
```

Which means you could use a variable there instead of hard coding it:

```
var target = 'temperature';

for (var i = 0; i < jsonObj.data.length; i++) { 
  if (jsonObj.data[i][target]) { 
    break;
  }
}

jsonObj.data[i][target].home = 24;
jsonObj.data[i][target].work = 20;
```

Comment: Thanks Dave. It works great! Do you know any way of doing this without array index? Sometimes, the location of the temperature field can be changed.

Comment: Using this code, I could find where the temperature is anyway.. It does not look elegant though..   if( jsonObj.data[i].temperature ) {jsonObj.data[2].temperature.home = 24;}
else {;}

Comment: @Mingoo: Yes, that's about what I would do in that case too. Ideally, maybe `data` could just not be an array? A structure like `jsonObj.data.temperature` would make things cleaner and easier.

Comment: Yes, that's right. But there would be other data such as windows open/close status as well. That's why it's an array. Thank you very much, and I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Great. It's very nice that I can select among several options because in each time the condition is different. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
jsonObj.data.push( {
  temperature : {
        "home" : 24,
        "work" : 20
  } 
} );
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know how to add it in a one shot, but I need to do it separately..