# Adding a attribute to a JSON object

Tags: json

I have a JSON object with few properties How Do I add properties dynamically to the object?

```
person({
   'name':Ajay,
    'age':21 });
```

If i want to add properties like gender or contact to this existing object , how to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add new attribute dynamically to the existing JSON array in Node](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23208674/add-new-attribute-dynamically-to-the-existing-json-array-in-node)

Comment: You didn't mentioned, which `scripting language` you are supporting. Without it anybody would be handicapped to answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have function named as person and you are sending a object in that function So to put it simple.

```
            var obj={"name":"Ajay",
                     "age":"21"
              };
             person(obj);
```

If you want to add more properties to your obj. You can do it like this:

```
       obj.sex="Male";
       obj.height="6";
       person(obj);
```

Comment: how did you know that the scripting language is JavaScript?

Comment: In a a json Obj you add prop. like this only . So i just guessed it .

Comment: Better to consult/clarify the author before assuming anything, otherwise there is an ocean to assume anything.

Comment: In any case the format of JSON will not change right  :)